# Divide a large array into chunks of varying sizes to store in a multidimensional array

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

[**3**, 0, 1, 4, **4**, 0, 3, 2, 1, **3**, 1, 2, 4, **3**, 3, 4, 2, **3**, 0, 4, 3]

The bold elements in the array above indicate how many elements following that element belong to that chunk, what is the best way to divide these chunks into arrays and store them in a multidimensional array where each row essentially holds a chunk so that we have something like this:

```
int numOfChunks = 5 //Assuming we already know the number of chunks in the array 
int[][] array = {  {0, 1, 4},
                   {0, 3, 2, 1},
                   {1, 2, 4},
                   {3, 4, 2},
                   {0, 4, 3}   }
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an alternative to pre-calculating the length of the array - use a List to store the int[] arrays as they are being extracted. Convert it to an array of the correct size at the end:

```
  public static int[][] blockSplitter(int[] data) {
    List<int[]> blocks = new ArrayList<int[]>();
    for (int i = 0; i < data.length;) {
      int blockSize = data[i];
      int[] block = Arrays.copyOfRange(data, i + 1, i + blockSize + 1);
      blocks.add(block);
      i += (blockSize + 1);
    }
    return (int[][]) blocks.toArray(new int[blocks.size()][]);
  }
```

Comment: This is the first approach I tried but instead of Lists I was using the 2D array to store the blocks in, I guess that's why it was throwing exceptions. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I think your only problem is to figure out the column size for each row. See the inline comments.

```
public static int[][] get2DArray(int[] raw){

    int max = 0; // Max number of items in a row
    int totalRows = 0;

    // Get the row with maximum elements and total number of rows
    for(int i = 0; i < raw.length;){

        if(raw[i] > max){
           max = raw[i];               
        }

        totalRows++;
        i += raw[i] + 1;

    }   

    // Declare a 2d array with just rows 
    // Since different rows can have different number of columns,
    // we cannot populate the column size yet
    int[][] array = new int[totalRows][];

    int ctr = 0; // items indices

    for(int i = 0; i < totalRows; i++){

        // Since now we know the column size for the current row, let's create
        array[i] = new int[raw[ctr]];

        // Loop from 0 to column size
        for(int j = 0; j < raw[ctr]; j++){
            // We use the row start + 1 to get the appropriate column value
            array[i][j] = raw[j + 1 + ctr];                   
        }

        // Let's point the ctr to the start of the next row
        ctr += raw[ctr] + 1;
    }    

    return array;
}
```

To test the method:

```
int[] raw = {3, 0, 1, 4, 4, 0, 3, 2, 1, 3, 1, 2, 4, 3, 3, 4, 2, 3, 0, 4, 3};
int[][] array = get2DArray(raw);

for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
    for(int j = 0; j < array[i].length; j++){
        System.out.print(array[i][j] + "\t");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Output:

```
0    1    4    
0    3    2    1    
1    2    4    
3    4    2    
0    4    3
```

Answer (score 0):

firstly you need to identified biggest number so that you can create multidimentional array of that number.

lets say in you example Biggest number is 4 then you need to define array of 4 and then arrange element.

if any element does not fit in requirement assign to 0 so that structure should be followed of 4x4

Answer (score 0):

*My solution is deliberately vague so as not so simply write the code for you.*

Two loops, one to count the number of extractable sections or chunks (rows), create a second array of this size then another loop to extract the second dimension of the second array (columns)

```
int i = 0;
int rows = 0; //extractable sections, in this case 5

do //if you know the number of chunks in advance, may not be needed
{
  //add value in array[i] to i
  //keep track of largest array[i] value
  rows++
}while(i<array.length)

//create new array of size 'rows' by the largest array[i] value

int i2 = 0;
do
{
  //create an array of the next array[i] numbers
  //put in rows[i2] and increment i2
  //add value of array[i] to i
}while(i<array.length)
```

Answer (score 0):

Google Guava Lists.partition

http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Lists.html#partition%28java.util.List,%20int%29

Great library, check it out